# nodejs crypto module privateEncrypt() always return same result

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, rsa, cryptojs

I am using RSA encryption with nodejs crypto module.

I want encrypt message with PRIVATE KEY and decrypt with PUBLIC KEY.
also always make different result with same message using padding scheme like encryption using public key.

So I used basic crypto module like below

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


var PRIVKEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'private.key'), 'utf8');
var PUBKEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'pub.key'), 'utf8');

// RSA PRIVATE ENCRYPT -> PUBLIC DECRYPT //
myMSG = "apple";
console.log('myMSG SIZE:', myMSG.length);

function privENC_pubDEC(originMSG){
 encmsg = crypto.privateEncrypt(PRIVKEY, Buffer.from(originMSG, 'utf8') ).toString('base64');
 msg = crypto.publicDecrypt(PUBKEY, Buffer.from(encmsg, 'base64'));
 console.log("Encrypted with private key : "+encmsg);
 console.log(msg.toString());
}

// RSA PUBLIC ENCRYPT -> PRVATE DECRYPT //
function pubENC_privDEC(originMSG){
 encmsg = crypto.publicEncrypt({key:PUBKEY, padding:crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING}, Buffer.from(originMSG, 'utf8') ).toString('base64');
 msg = crypto.privateDecrypt({key:PRIVKEY, padding:crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING}, Buffer.from(encmsg, 'base64'));
 console.log("\nEncrypted with public key : "+encmsg);
 console.log(msg.toString());
}

privENC_pubDEC(myMSG);
pubENC_privDEC(myMSG);
```

Result

```
C:\Users\LSW>node crypto.js
myMSG SIZE: 5
Encrypted with private key : fbUZwj+UZP92HQYRc+EJTqSztJTY/Sit5axPZ0NVBuDAC8ZwvvC96pxxDGpra4Yg8MjcXyjvnT8rrrgHu0T0wA==
apple

Encrypted with public key : ze+5TdWtR8hkpNPIVa5HSasOxs3Pr8FA/1/zUGqDUQmIhs/miWt5pgU9kIAiryKfgGa0+p9RfHPMwZ1VMSA7Bw==
apple

C:\Users\LSW>node crypto.js
myMSG SIZE: 5
Encrypted with private key : fbUZwj+UZP92HQYRc+EJTqSztJTY/Sit5axPZ0NVBuDAC8ZwvvC96pxxDGpra4Yg8MjcXyjvnT8rrrgHu0T0wA==
apple

Encrypted with public key : OdEpjloUDWI8+YjWkE5cmBC/fJL2QnRLKBXfjaP5h5qyB1OMcm9JGGNSTiAAL2u8O5jjdQAavB9Rn+cdRDjLyA==
apple

C:\Users\LSW>node crypto.js
myMSG SIZE: 5
Encrypted with private key : fbUZwj+UZP92HQYRc+EJTqSztJTY/Sit5axPZ0NVBuDAC8ZwvvC96pxxDGpra4Yg8MjcXyjvnT8rrrgHu0T0wA==
apple

Encrypted with public key : INspxkyFu2AWGVYwSvOGOPH1fhE3qVVxiqz+SmyHU8wTDNKHj4gVVHqO+8AZOJvi4NfyekI2MMwpFDU4mUjEXA==
apple
```

PUBLIC ENCRYPT -> PRVATE DECRYPT  is operated well I expected. it always return different result because of padding scheme.

But PRIVATE ENCRYPT -> PUBLIC DECRYPT is always return same message although used padding scheme.

Is there any solution make it different message with Nodejs crypto module???

Comment: You need [RSA-OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding)

Comment: @kelalaka RSA-OAEP is for encrypting and decrypting and actually supported and the default for `crypto`. The "problem" is with the signing and what is needed is [RSA-PSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme). See [my answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194706/1380680).

Comment: Yes, if we talk about private encryption as signing. signing != private encryption.

Comment: @kelalaka I have updated my answer with an explanation about signing (as opposed to private encryption). This should make it more clear. With regard to your comment, I wonder if there is a reason to use `privateEncrypt()` for purposes other than signing.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek If you look at OpenSLL RSA [sign.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c) they have `RSA_sign` function. The problem occurs due incorrect education. See [Cornell Univ.'s correction](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php). There were a post at Crypto that list the signature and encryption algorithms based only public key, that only RSA has this problem. In Cryptography context, singing != encryption. Even it is not advised to use same [keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12138/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks, interesting read. And the problem is aggravated by some implementors. For example, the `RSA_sign` function that you refer to [may invoke a function RSA_private_encrypt()](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1/crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c#L103) :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behavior according to the padding schemes for RSA signing and encryption as implemented by OpenSSL, [which `crypto` leverages](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto).

I am not sure what you want to use the functions [`privateEncrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_privateencrypt_privatekey_buffer) and [`publicDecrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicdecrypt_key_buffer) for. If your intent is to sign data, then see my update below. Anyway, for these functions, the `crypto` documentation explains that it only exposes `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING` which OpenSSL maps to the deterministic RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 padding scheme under the hood. This means that for the same key and the same data, the resulting data will be the same.

For encryption and decryption, with [`publicEncrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_key_buffer) and [`privateDecrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_key_buffer), you have selected the `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING` mode. This translates to the RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5, a scheme that includes random elements, which cause the different outputs that you observe in your repeated runs. According to the documentation, `crypto` uses `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` padding by default. This stands for [Optimal asymmetric encryption padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding), which is non-deterministic as well.

For a summary of the PKCS#1-defined schemes, see [PKCS#1 Schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1#Schemes).

---

Update: You may want to use the [`Sign class`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign) instead of the `privateEncrypt()` and `publicDecrypt()` functions. Its [`sign`()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_sign_sign_privatekey_outputencoding) function does support a probabilistic padding mode, which OpenSSL supports via RSASSA-PSS. Using your example code as a starting point, it would look something like this:

```
const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256')
sign.update(Buffer.from(originMSG, 'utf8'))
signature = sign.sign({key:PRIVKEY, padding:crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING}).toString('base64')
```

The signature will be different every time. Note that you can not "decrypt" it, it is a one-way operation. You can only verify it, using the public key with the [`Verify`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_verify) class:

```
const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256')
verify.update(Buffer.from(originMSG, 'utf8'))
verifyRes = verify.verify({key:PUBKEY, padding:crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING}, Buffer.from(signature, 'base64'))
```

Comment: @cockroach54 My pleasure, your question was well posed and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Um.. may I ask you one more??? 
I am planning to embed the PUBLIC KEY in  client app and PRIVATE KEY in admin app.

Admin app user encrypt some kind of code (encrypted code must be different randmly) and give it to the client app. client only decrypt code but should not know how to encrypt it.

In this case, if admin use PUBLIC KEY and client use PRIVATE KEY, client can make PUBLIC KEY using PRIVATE KEY. this is a problem.

Could I customize  privateEncrypt() use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 --> RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 ???

Comment: @cockroach54 This is too big to respond to in a comment, please submit it as a new question to get a proper answer...